# iOS5 Storyboard UIViewController which init method is called by the storyboard?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ios5, storyboard

Which `init` method is called by the storyboard for `UIViewControllers` added to the storyboard?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

The initializer used is `initWithCoder:`

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
```

Then afterwards you will also get an `awakeFromNib` message.

Comment: Am I the only one who finds it strange that the default(?) init isn't called from initWithCoder?

Comment: No, it is not the designated init, inits should call another init with (generally) more parameters, which would then call [super init]. In this case it seems that initWithCoder is the designated init

Comment: initWithCoder: is a designated initializer of any class that implements NSCoding.

Answer (score 5):

I believe it is `awakeFromNib`

Comment: awakeFromNib gets called too since our `UIViewControllers` are being "canned" in your .storyboard file (the equivalent of the "old" nibs)

Comment: The difference (which can be important) between `awakeFromNib` and the `init*` methods is that they return an instance, `awakeFromNib` doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

It is the `- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder`

So if you have to do a custom init, let's say using a custom Pager Controller you have to do there like

```
    - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {

        self = [super initWithCoder:decoder];
        return [self initWithViewControllers:@[self.playerViewController, self.categoriesViewController]
                  andTitles:@[@"Player",@"Categories"]];
    }
```